# Condition for an operator on a real space to be skew adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to show that an operator $A$ on a real inner product space is skew adjoint if and only if $<Ax,x>=0$ for all vectors $x$. How do I show this?

I showed that an operator $A$ on a complex inner product space is self-adjoint iff $<Ax,x>$ is real for all $x$. I tried to proceed along the same lines, but that approach doesn't seem to be working here. Is there a trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

We have a real inner product space and $A^T=-A$. Hence:

$<Ax,x>=<x,A^Tx>=<x,-Ax>=-<x,Ax>=-<Ax,x>$